# Coding specifications for Facebook fan page iframes

Tags: facebook, iframe

I designed my fan page for Facebook which is 520 px wide and 800 px tall. Now the most interesting part comes up - slicing and coding to fit Facebook iframe.
Is there any coding specifications for making HTML/CSS for my Facebook fan page? I guess I must be careful with Java script. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Applications running in Facebook Page tabs are simply Web Pages/Applications working in `iframe` tag. There is no coding standards or specifications for this and you may use any technology (that allows development of Web Pages/Applications). You're not limited by `HTML`/`CSS`/`JavaScript` here...

You should read [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) and [Page Tab Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/).